# Need help useing a Iterator in java

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, data-structures, listiterator

I am trying to print out a array list of linked lists of size 8 using an Iterator here is what I have so far

```
ArrayList<LinkedList> myaol = new ArrayList<>();//my array which the linked lists are created when needed
public void printList(Iterator<Gen> itr)//gen is the generic data type 
{
     while( this.hasNext() )
     {    
          System.out.println(this.next());
     }      
}
```

I under stand how to iterate through one linked list but am not sure how to go to the next index of the the arraylist in order to get every linked list any help would be much appreciated

Comment: this.hasNext() ... ? What is outer class for the printList() method?

Comment: This.hasnext() is checking to see if itr has another value after the current one

Comment: this.hasNext() implies your extending an Iterator or did you mean itr.hasNext(), please can you post the rest of your code so we can see better what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an ArrayList of LinkedLists, you can get each LinkedList with the following code, and do whatever you want to do with the LinkedLists...

```
ArrayList<LinkedList> myaol = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<LinkedList> itr = myaol.iterator();
 while (itr.hasNext()) {
      LinkedList myList = itr.next();
    }
```

You can print the list like that

```
  // print the list
  System.out.println("LinkedList:" + myList);

  // create an array and copy the list to it
  Object[] array = myList.toArray();

  // print the array
  for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println("Array:" + array[i]);
  }
```